# Ao criar uma imageView e TextView via código como remover via código?

Tags: java, android, xml

Bom crie dessa maneira

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Alguma coisa");
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutVertical);
linear.addView(textView);
```

e para remover fiz assim

```
linear.removeView(textView);
```

Mas não a removeu será que outra maneira de remover?

Comment: Não esqueça que tem de usar em `removeView(textView)` a mesma instancia de `textView` que usou em `addView(textView)`

Comment: Não seria mais facil alterar a visibilidade para Gone?
textView.setVisibility(Visible.GONE);

Comment: @ramaral você está se referindo ao `linear`?

Comment: Aos dois, tanto ao `linear` como ao `textview`

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso utilize o método setVisibility da classe TextView, passando como parametro View.GONE, assim o elemento não vai ser visível, nem ocupará espaço no LinearLayout.

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```